# Spring MVC Custom Converter for JSON data not working

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, typeconverter

I am creating a test application to to achieve conversion from JSON String to Employee Object before being passed to the controller.

Here are the key steps performed

- **Creation of Employee.java Class** : Domain Object
- **Creation of EmployeeManagementController.java class** : Spring MVC Controller for Managing Employee
- **Creation of EmployeeConverter.java** : Custom Converter for Converting JSON String to Employee Object.
- **Creation of employee-servlet.xml** : Spring Configuration file
- **Creation of web.xml** : The Deployment Descriptor

*Employee.java*

```
package com.bluebench.training.domain;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("employee")
public class Employee {

    private PersonalDetail personal;
    private EducationDetail education;
    private WorkExperienceDetail experience;


    // Getters and Setters

}
```

other domain objects are also defined

*EmployeeManagementController.java*

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.bluebench.training.domain.Employee;

@Controller
public class EmployeeManagementController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/ems/add/employee",method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes="application/json",produces="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody int addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee emp){
        System.out.println("RAGHAVE");
        System.out.println(emp.getPersonal().getName());
        int empId = 20;
        return empId;
    }




}
```

*EmployeeConverter.java*

```
package com.bluebench.training.converter;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;

import com.bluebench.training.domain.Employee;

public class EmployeeConverter implements Converter<String,Employee>{

    @Override
    public Employee convert(String json) {
        System.out.println("Inside convert()");
        Employee emp = null;
        try {
            emp = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json,Employee.class);
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
        return emp;
    }




}
```

*employee-servlet.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

            <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
                xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

                <context:component-scan base-package="com.bluebench.training"/>

                <mvc:annotation-driven  conversion-service="conversionService"/>

                <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>          

                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
                    <property name="mediaTypes">
                        <map>
                            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                            <entry key="xml" value="text/xml" />
                            <entry key="htm" value="text/html" />
                        </map>
                    </property>
                    <property name="defaultContentType" value="text/html"/>
                </bean>

                <bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
                    <property name="converters">
                        <list>
                            <bean class="com.bluebench.training.converter.EmployeeConverter"/>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>

            </beans>
```

*web.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>PROJECT_38_SpringMVCRESTFul</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>employee</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>employee</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/employee-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>



</web-app>
```

I am using Firefox RestClient to Test it.

Here is the JSON which correctly maps to the Employee object.

```
{"personal":{"name":"Raghave","age":33,"phoneNumber":"9594511111","address":"101, software appartment, software land , mumbai"},"education":{"qualifications":[{"insititute":"Amity University","degree":"Bachelor of Science","yearOfPassing":"2007","percentage":62.0}]},"experience":{"experience":[{"companyName":"QTBM","designation":"Programmer","years":3,"salary":12000.0},{"companyName":"Polaris","designation":"Software Developer","years":1,"salary":24000.0},{"companyName":"Ness","designation":"Senior Software Engineer","years":2,"salary":50000.0},{"companyName":"JPMC","designation":"Senior Applications Developer","years":1,"salary":120000.0}]}}
```

There is no Exception thrown and the controller does receive the Employee Object in the addEmployee() method. But its not via converter. The Converter is not invoked. I dont know why ? I dont want to use init binders or @Valid. I wanted to know where am i going wrong. how to make it work?

Comment: First of all, choose between `@Component` and a `<bean>` declaration. Don't use both.

Comment: sorry my bad, i will change, the bigger question is how to make the converter be invoked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've confused Spring's general type conversion support that uses Converters and the ConversionService with its support for HTTP message conversion that is specifically designed for converting web requests and responses and understands media types (like application/json that you're using). HTTP message conversion uses instance of HttpMessageConverter.

You don't actually need a custom converter in this case. Spring's MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter is being used to perform the conversion automatically. The conversion can be performed automatically because, presumably (you haven't posted the setters so I'm making an educated guess), the setter methods in Employee match the JSON, i.e. setName, setAge, setPhoneNumber etc.

Arguably, the code that you've got is already working. You can safely delete your custom converter, have the same functionality, and have less code to maintain. If you really want to use a custom converter, you'll need to implement HttpMessageConverter and configure it before/in place of MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.

Comment: Thanks Andy for de-mystifying the difference between message converters. It spring spring source has lost in defining clear boundaries amongst Web Argument Resolvers ,InitBinders and Property editors, Type Converters, Message Converters and Formatters. But this also brings me to define my actual requirement. This was just a PoC that i can apply converter in a situation that would require Custom Conversion. I think Message Converter is what i actually need my real application.

Comment: In our actual application we are trying to achieve direct conversion of a JSON to PDF i.e. JSON would be parsed to Custom Objects like Document which in turn contain references to Itext Objects. The problem is couple of Itext beans do not have getters and/or setters which causes Jackson Parser to throw exceptions if i directly try to map JSON to itext objects. For this i am required to create an intermediate TemplateMapper custom Object that performs necessary copying to Itext Object, so i cant go ahead without any converter or as you said message converter here. Can you provide any resource?

Comment: That's probably better dealt with in a separate question. You'll either be looking to register a custom HttpMessageConverter, or to customize the Jackson ObjectMapper that Spring's using for the automatic conversion.

Comment: Well i already applied both the approach, extending the ObjectMapper does not work well. It was resulting in an infinite recursive loop leading to Stack Overflow Exception. This is because i was calling super.readValue() from within parse() method while overriding it. I uderstood that readValue() itself calls the parse() method and results in an infinite recusrion. Anyways extending the HttpMessageConverter did work wonders for me. Thanks alot!.